# Python try except continue fails to print expected results

Tags: python, exception, dictionary, python-2.7

Can someone point out where am I going wrong, What is actually happening here exactly with except continue or a better way to tackle this problem.

```
dic = {'arun': 123213, 'hari': 31212, 'akila': 321, 'varun': 12132, 'apple': 3212}
u1 = {'arun': 123123, 'orange': 1324214}
u2 = {'akila': 1234124, 'apple': 123123}
u3 = {'hari': 144}
u4 = {'anna': 23322}
for key, value in dic.iteritems():
    try:
        A = u1[key]
        B = u2[key]
        C = u3[key]
        D = u4[key]

    except KeyError:
        continue
    print A, B, C, D  # fails to print
```

Comment: What results do you expect?

Comment: @Kevin display the matched values of dicts u1, u2, u3 and u4 for every key (word) in dictionary dic

Comment: Use `pass` instead of `continue` if you want to see some results.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That would be a bad idea. If he gets an exception the first time through, `pass` will give him a `NameError`; if he gets an exception after the first time through, `pass` will cause him to print out the values from the previous loop…

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary pass doesn't fix my issue

Comment: @abarnert I agree it's a bad idea, I would have used `dict.get` too, but as he's not getting any output he's not able to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `continue` will skip to the next key from `dic` if any lookup fails.  You want to use an operation which is guaranteed to give a result even if the key is not found, e.g. [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
for key, value in dic.iteritems():
    A = u1.get(key)  # A is None if not found
    # ...
    print A, B, C, D
```

Comment: thx! this works.. is there a way to return 0 instead of None since I am doing further computations using the returned values. I don't want to add a check condition for None after every dict search.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar use `u1.get(key,0)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'uX' dictionaries do not have the same keys as 'dic' so it is failing when trying to retrieve those values. Then you are catching the exception and calling 'continue' which automatically jumps back to the top of your loop before your print statement executes.

Try taking out the try/except statement and the Python interpreter will spit out an error of exactly where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

- `u2['hari']` will raise an exception
- `u3['akila']` will also raise an exception
- `u4['varun']` will again also raise an exception

you are trying each time to use a item from a dictionary although the item doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic = {'arun': 123213, 'hari': 31212, 'akila': 321, 'varun': 12132, 'apple': 3212}
u1 = {'arun': 123123, 'orange': 1324214}
u2 = {'akila': 1234124, 'apple': 123123}
u3 = {'hari': 144}
u4 = {'anna': 23322}

for key in dic:
    print list(d.get(key) for d in (u1, u2, u3, u4))
```

It prints your output as a list:

```
>>> for key in dic:
...     print list(d.get(key) for d in (u1, u2, u3, u4))
... 
[123123, None, None, None]
[None, 1234124, None, None]
[None, 123123, None, None]
[None, None, 144, None]
[None, None, None, None]
```